# Why @Id UUID in validator not null on persist operation?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator

I have an entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@MappedSuperclass
@ValidUuidPrimaryEntity
public class UuidPrimaryEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6602362437085355133L;

    @Id
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    @Column(name = "gid")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "hibernate-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;
}
```

When my entity comes to validator via JPA repository

```
public class UuidPrimaryEntityValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidUuidPrimaryEntity, UuidPrimaryEntity > {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidUuidPrimaryEntity constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(UuidPrimaryEntity value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

the id field (value.getId()) is not null. So I can't check if the entity is new

```
ext.hibernateVersion = '5.0.2.Final'
ext.hibernateValidatorVersion = '5.2.1.Final'
```

Comment: Where is your constraint `ValidUuidPrimaryEntity` used? It seems to be a class level constraint for UuidPrimaryEntity, but I don't see it in your example. And what exactly is it you are asking?

Comment: Thnx, I edited the question. The goal of this issue is to understand is it correct that id value of not persisted entity generated before validating was done